# Program SGILL's when linking OpenCV

Tags: c++, linux, opencv, gdb, illegal-instruction

I know this question is similar to may other ones but none of them seem to solve my problem.

**Symptoms**

- Trivially build and run `gdb_test` with gdb.
- Program `SIGILL`'s:

---

```
~/projects/gdb_test/build> gdb gdb_test           
GNU gdb (GDB; openSUSE Tumbleweed) 8.3.1
(...)

For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word"...
Reading symbols from gdb_test...
(gdb) r
Starting program: /home/jaques/projects/gdb_test/build/gdb_test 
Missing separate debuginfos, use: zypper install glibc-debuginfo-2.31-5.9.x86_64
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib64/libthread_db.so.1".
[New Thread 0x7fffebae8700 (LWP 1210)]
[New Thread 0x7fffeb2e7700 (LWP 1211)]
[New Thread 0x7fffe6ae6700 (LWP 1212)]

Thread 1 "gdb_test" received signal SIGILL, Illegal instruction.
0x00007ffff7d90617 in ?? () from /usr/lib64/libopencv_gapi.so.4.2

(gdb)
```

---

**Sample project:**

"main.cpp"

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    std::cout << "Hello, world!" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)
project(gdb_test)

find_package( OpenCV REQUIRED )    # Works fine if this line is removed.

add_executable(gdb_test main.cpp)
install(TARGETS gdb_test RUNTIME DESTINATION bin)
```

**Environment**

- Linux box running updated OpenSuse:

> NAME="openSUSE Tumbleweed"
> VERSION="20200622"

- G++ 10.1.1
- GDB 8.3.1
- opencv-devel 4.2.0-4.1
- Arch x86_64
- Not stripped, with debug info executable:

> gdb_test/build> file gdb_test  gdb_test: ELF 64-bit LSB executable,
> x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter
> /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2,
> BuildID[sha1]=28f8c835686d92c15cb8b0cfb201c5f45a8a89c7, for GNU/Linux
> 3.2.0, with debug_info, not stripped

---

What can be wrong?

How to solve?

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried a different OpenCV version?

Comment: I downgraded from opencv-devel-4.2.0-4.1.x86_64 to opencv3-3.4.9-2.4.x86_64 and it is not crashing anymore...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your comment:

> I downgraded from opencv-devel-4.2.0-4.1.x86_64 to opencv3-3.4.9-2.4.x86_64 and it is not crashing anymore..

I can only conclude the package is broken.

In case you really need OpenCV 4, I suggest you to build from sources.

Comment: Aside from the package being outright broken, I can imagine it having been built for a different architecture than it is being used on, or -- most likely, IMO -- having been being compiled with options that enable CPU or GPU features that are present on the machine where it was built but not on the machine where it is used.  One might still characterize either of those as "broken", but it's a rather more nuanced matter than that would make it seem.

Comment: Yes, great point @JohnBollinger.This package can work perfectly on different setups. It is not an easy task to guarantee it works on all possible combinations.